# Swig template &nbsp; cannot converted in space

Tags: swig-template

I'm using [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) as my template engine.  I am unable to use `safe` to pass-through a string without additional escaping.

```
my_var = "<p>The new buyer can expect a minimal buyers PIP during&nbsp;transfer.</p>";
```

In the template:

```
{{ my_var|safe }}
```

I would expect the value of `my_var` to be passed through as-is.  Instead, the following is output:

```
<p>The new buyer can expect a minimal buyers PIP during&amp;nbsp;transfer.</p>
```

The key to this problem is that `&nbsp;` becomes `&amp;nbsp;`.

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: What's the **actual** output?  Not what the browser is rendering, but the raw HTML being output.

Comment: @Brad "The new buyer can expect a minimal buyers PIP during&amp;nbsp;transfer."

Comment: No `<p>` and `</p>`?  Something else is going on here.  The code above will not have the output you show.  Is this really the entire code needed to reproduce this problem?  If it is, file a Swig bug.

Comment: @Brad Yes. I am retrieving this to database <p>The new buyer can expect a minimal buyers PIP during "&nbsp;" transfer.</p>.